# android FilenameFilter dirs

Tags: java, android, mp3

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
FilenameFilter mp3Filter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        if (name.endsWith(".mp3")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
FilenameFilter dirFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        String n = name.toLowerCase();
        if (n.startsWith(".") || n.contains("notifications") || n.contains("ringtones") || n.contains("alarms")) {
            return false;
        }
        File f = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name);
        return f.isDirectory();
    }
};

private void GetMp3s(File root) {
    String[] mp3s = root.list(mp3Filter);
    for (int i=0; i<mp3s.length; i++)
        files.add(root+"/"+mp3s[i]);
    String[] dirs = root.list(dirFilter);
    for (int i=0; i<dirs.length; i++)
        GetMp3s(new File(root+"/"+dirs[i]));
};
```

the `mp3Filter` works just fine, and the dir filter only returns true if the file is a directory, but the `n.contains()` stuff isn't working - ie. I get return true for directories named "notifications" etc.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show the function call?

Comment: `File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
  GetMp3s(root);` ... _files_ is an ArrayList<String> and i get everything i want in there, but i also get files from the notifications dir

Comment: I thought dirFilter accept() was the problem. Can you post that method call

Comment: accept() isn't manually called, File.list(FilenameFilter ff) calls it... see: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29)

Comment: i just tried running the same code in the emulator after pushing some files on it and the dirFilter does work... but it doesn't work on my htc sensation (running stock 4.0.3)